# how to get separate x screen multi-monitor working

Tags: xorg

Just upgraded to 14.04 and after rebooting my secondary monitor isn't working the way it was before the upgrade. I tried to get it back working but it doesn't seem to be working this time. Before I had both monitors as separate x screens and I configured this through Nvidia x server settings.

Now my second monitor has a black background but nothing else. I can still move my cursor to it but can't do anything on it. My xorg.conf file is at the bottom of this post.

Any one got any ideas? If you need any more info just ask.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 337.12  (buildd@charichuelo)  Wed Apr  9 12:25:02 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0"
Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "BenQ GW2265"
HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor1"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "HP L1740"
HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650"
Option         "Coolbits" "4"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650"
Option         "Coolbits" "4"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device1"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

A bit more info. when I go to System Settings > Screen Display only my main monitor is detected. I'm pretty sure my second monitor was there before.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to do the same thing (setup 2 xscreens) but it's not working i get only one monitor working (xscreen0) did you find out how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The same exact thing just happened to me.  I looked in `/etc/X11`, and I believe my `xorg.conf` file was renamed to `xorg.conf.MMDDYYYY` where MMDDYYYY were set to today's date (the day I did the upgrade).

I copied this `xorg.conf.MMDDYYY` file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, rebooted, and my 2nd monitor returned to life.  Maybe you won't have as easy a time, but this worked for me.

Comment: Yeah I tried this but the xorg.conf.MMDDYYYY wasn't setup the same as it was before. Both monitors work when they use the same xscreen but won't when I try to use two separate xscreens. One for each monitor.